# duality and nonlinear optimization

Tags: optimization

If at a feasible point (x,y) we get  p*=d* that means the point is optimal.

Looking at the example: 
                         min (-x-y)
                         subject to: 
                                 xy<=4
                                 0<=x<=4
                                 0<=y<=8
I define  X={(x,y)| 0<=x<=4,  0<=y<=8}  and looking for the minimum of the Lagrangian (with one lamda for xy-4<=0) and maximum of the dual function (lamda = 0.5) I get x=y=2 which results in p*=-4=d*. But the feasible point x=0.5, y=8 yields p*=-8.5 < -4 !!
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the introduction of slack variables like $\epsilon$
With this additional variable the probem can be formulated as

$$
L(x,y,\lambda,\epsilon) = -(x+y)+\lambda(x y - 4-\epsilon^2)
$$

The stationary pints can be obtained by solving

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\lambda y & = & 1\\
\lambda x & = & 1\\
x y -4 & = & \epsilon\\
\lambda \epsilon & = & 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Solving we get

$x=2,y=2,\lambda = 1/2,\epsilon = 0$ which indicates that the stationary point is at the boundary ($\epsilon = 0$)

but this is not the solution because $\lambda > 0$ indicating that the objective function and the restriction function grow in the same direction hence the problem has an unbounded solution

For a minimum problem with an active restriction we need

$$
-(-1,-1) + \lambda (2,2) = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda < 0
$$

Comment: The function (-x-y) and the function (xy-4) at the point (2,2) grow in exactly opposite direction. Can a solution be unbounded in a finite region?

Comment: Minimization requires that $-(-1,-1) + \lambda(2,2) = 0$ which implies on $\lambda < 0$ to be active the restriction.

Comment: gradient of f(x,y) is (-1,-1). why -(-1,-1)?

Comment: Because it  is a minimization problem.